# failed cs-import-documents command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudsearch

I executed following command

```
cs-import-documents -format json --source https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/* --domain-name mydomain
```

I got following message.

```
Connecting to CloudSearch in region [us-east-1]
Source file not found at the location https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/**
No source found.
```

The s3 bucket and path is absolutely correct, because I copied path from S3 console.

- I successed the uploading when I set localfilepath `--source directory/*`
- I have `CloudSearchFullAccess` and `AmazonS3FullAccess` on IAM policy.

How can I resolve?

Thanks.